# What values are returned by event_data(EVENT_INSTANCE/objecttype)

Tags: sql-server

I'm into SQL Server 2014 and working on `eventdata()`. I noticed that this event returns the object type, like 'PROCEDURE'. Is there a document that lists all the values that this "objectType" returns?

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN [DDL Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx) page is probably what you want, but the page for [EVENTDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx) references the [Microsoft SQL Server XML Schemas](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/) Web page which includes a link to the [SQL Server Event Data Schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/) which will give you the definitive answer.

Within events.xsd ObjectType is defined as SSWNAMEType which is basically nvarchar(128), unfortunately not a choice type element. However, SQL Server has a very widely used 'object type' in [sys.objects.type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190324.aspx) which should give you a start on the possible database level objects. Alternatively, look at the [DDL Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx) and you might be able to infer the possible objects types from the event name.

Comment: Thanks @Rhys. I'm actually looking for the exact value that objectType returns and been in that document but nothing seems to match the output that event_instance/objectType is giving.

Comment: Thanks @Rhys. The links you provided helped. Though the object types that the event_instance return differs from what sys.objects.type and sys.object_type_desc, (Like 'PROCEDURE' vs 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE', it somehow points me to where I want to achieve. Difficult it may seem, what I did was I created db objects and let the DB Trigger prints the EVENT_INSTANCE/objecttype.